# What other forms of wasted kinetic energy are there besides the forms of light, heat, and sound?

Tags: energy, momentum, collision

This is very basic physics but I'm a little stumped. We're working on 2 dimensional collisions in our lab class, and we have a video of two pucks colliding against each other. After working out before and after kinetic energy, we know that the collision is highly inelastic, as it loses 58% of its initial kinetic energy. We're trying to figure out where that lost energy has gone.

We have already crossed out friction causing heat because our velocities of the two pucks are constant before and after collision. We also know it's not deformation of the pucks because they aren't deformed. There's no light being created, and though I'm almost certain there's sound, we were given a video that didn't have even have sound, so I'm doubting that's the main reason there's such a significant kinetic energy loss. I've contacted my professor about this, and the clue he gave was to pay attention to the motion of the pucks after collision.

The only noticeable thing about the motion of the pucks after collision is that one puck's speed becomes significantly slower while the other one's speed remains the same. However, I'm confused about how this would give us a clue to what form the wasted kinetic energy takes. It's neither heat, light, nor sound, but those are the only results I'm finding online when I search up "forms of lost energy". Could someone give me a clue as to what the form of energy might be? I'm assuming it has to do with the reduced speed of the pucks after collision?

Comment: Is it possible that the pucks tilt a little bit when they collide?  If so, there would be several possible forces that could slow one of the pucks.  You might do well to add a little weight to the "non-slowed" puck and re-try the experiment.

Comment: There must be some deformation of material on impact, even if only temporary, which will create heat and sound.

Comment: Are you actually conducting the experiment? If so, in order to rule out loss of kinetic energy due to sliding friction you would need to make the before and after velocity measurements as soon as possible before and after the collision. You can't rule out ice friction. Given enough time the pucks would come to rest.

Comment: @Bob D Unfortunately, we're not conducting any in class experiments with covid going on - meaning all we received to do analysis was a 2 second video and Capstone software to analyze. We can't do any separate experiments - just that single video.

Comment: @AdrianHoward There was a very slight temporary deformation that was barely visible, where the puck got narrower and more elliptical than circular momentarily before turning back to a circular shape. My original hypothesis was that the loss of kinetic energy was due to that, but the professor said it was something else.